# For certain rows, copying values of a set of columns to another, of the same data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I was expecting the following line of code to copy values from col4 and col5 (for rows that satisfy the filter) to col1 and col2 of the same rows. However, col1 and col2 remain unchanged.

```
df[['col1', 'col2']][df['col3'].isnull()] = df[df['col3'].isnull()][['col4', 'col5']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use the mask on the RHS:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[df['col3'].isnull()][['col4', 'col5']]
```

Comment: It worked ! Thanks ! Can you explain why this does not result in a dimensions mismatch error?

Comment: Basically the LHS uses the index of the RHS to work out what rows to update ... btw don't worry, this took me ages before I worked it out the first time!